# 通電していない時に、モーターの軸が回りません

Tags: ハードウェア

すみません、プログラミングの質問ではないです。しかしこのサイトでは工学系の質問もいくつか見受けられるので、質問させていただきます。

本題

通電していない時に、モーターの軸が回りません。モーターは、Pololu 172:1 金属ギヤードモータ 25Dx71L mm HP 6V 48CPRエンコーダ付きです。
新品なうえに、Arduinoからの入力電圧でプログラムした通りには動いてくれるので、モーターそのもの故障ではないと思います。

しかし、最初にも述べた通り通電していない時に、モーターの軸が全く回りません。指で回そうとしても動きませんし、モーターにタイヤをつけて手で回そうとすると、軸はビクともせず、タイヤの接続部が壊れました。軸をバイスで固定して回そうとしても、ビクともせず、さらに力をかけることも出来ましたが壊れそうなのでやめました。

こんなに軸がかたいことってあるのでしょうか？また何が原因と考えられるでしょうか？

Comment: 回らないことで何か困ることはありますか？単なる思い込みの可能性もあるので、可能であれば購入元・販売元などに問い合わせた方が確実な回答が得られる場合もあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分は倒立振子を作っています。二輪を固定して、車体を振り子のように見立てて、時間と振り子の角度のグラフを出し、モーターと車体の粘性摩擦係数を知りたいのです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

名前からして 172:1 の減速ギアが入っている様子。常識的に考えて軸側から手で回して回るわけがないです。手で回せたら故障ですので安心してください。

この手の減速ギア入りモーターを軸側から回すといろいろと危険です（発電機動作して感電したりとか）ダメ、絶対。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分は倒立振子を作っています。二輪を固定して、車体を振り子のように見立てて、時間と振り子の角度のグラフを出し、モーターと車体の粘性摩擦係数を知りたいのですが、どうやら無理そうですね。他にどのような同定方法がありますでしょうか

Comment: それは別途新規質問を立てるとよいですね（答えられる人がいるかどうかはまた別ですが：オイラもメカのほうは専門ではないっス）